# In openLayers 6.x how i can access the variables?

Tags: javascript, gis, openlayers-6

I have the following declaration of my geozone variable

```
var geozonas = new VectorLayer({
    source: new VectorSource({
      url:'https://geo.anantara.cl/maps/json/geozone2.json',
      format: new GeoJSON()
    })
  });
```

I would like to access the **features** of that variable **geozonas** inside this code, how can I do it?

```
geolocation.on('change:position', function() {
  var coordinates = geolocation.getPosition();
  positionFeature.setGeometry(coordinates ?
    new Point(coordinates) : null);
    view.setCenter(coordinates);
});
```

I understand that the framework design avoids the use of global variables, how can they be referenced then?

Thanks in advance
Pablo

Comment: `geozonas.getSource().getFeatures()`

Comment: Mate, thanks for your hint, but the problem is geozonas variable is defined out of geolcation helper class, when i try to access i see undefined, so i know openlayers dont like global variables but in this case i need to access geozonas from inside geolation, how i can do it?

Comment: There no no reason why your layer variable cannot have similar scope to the `view` variable you are accessing in the callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was correct what Mike indicated, that if, in order to access the features, I had to somehow realize that it was all loaded, a topic that is already discussed in the FAQ and from there just access the layer.